# Get padding from theme/make native sidebar in PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5

I'm trying to make a native looking sidebar that can expand and collapse in PyQt5. I've managed to create this:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtProperty
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class Sidebar(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, buttons: list = None):
        super().__init__()
        
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.setFont(font)
        self.setIconSize(QSize(35, 35))

        for button in buttons:
            self.addItem(button)
        
        self.maxWidth = self.sizeHintForColumn(0) + 10

        iconWidth = self.iconSize().width()
        self.minWidth = iconWidth + 16
        self.awidth = self.minWidth
        
        self.expandAnimation = QPropertyAnimation(self, b'awidth')
        self.expandAnimation.setEndValue(self.maxWidth)
        self.expandAnimation.setDuration(200)
        self.expandAnimation.setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve.InOutCubic)
        
        self.contractAnimation = QPropertyAnimation(self, b'awidth')
        self.contractAnimation.setEndValue(self.minWidth)
        self.contractAnimation.setDuration(200)
        self.contractAnimation.setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve.InOutCubic)

        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setTextElideMode(Qt.TextElideMode.ElideNone)
        

    def leaveEvent(self, e) -> None:
        self.contractAnimation.start()
    
    def enterEvent(self, e) -> None:
        self.expandAnimation.start()


    @pyqtProperty(int)
    def awidth(self) -> int:
        return self._awidth
    
    @awidth.setter
    def awidth(self, value) -> None:
        self._awidth = value
        super().setFixedWidth(self._awidth)
    

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.buttonState = False
        self.setMinimumSize(500, 300)
        
        button1 = QListWidgetItem(QIcon.fromTheme('battery'), 'Button 1')
        button2 = QListWidgetItem(QIcon.fromTheme('computer'), 'Button 2')
        button3 = QListWidgetItem(QIcon.fromTheme('camera-web'), 'Button 3')
        self.sidebar = Sidebar([button1, button2, button3])
        self.sidebar.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Policy.Maximum, QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding)
        
        self.mainWidget = QPushButton()
        self.mainWidget.setText('0')
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.mainWidget.setFont(font)
        self.mainWidget.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Policy.Preferred)
        self.mainWidget.pressed.connect(self.buttonPressed)


        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.sidebar)
        layout.addWidget(self.mainWidget)
        centralWidget = QWidget()
        centralWidget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        
        self.sidebar.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.sidebarChanged)


    def sidebarChanged(self):
        selection = self.sidebar.selectedIndexes()[0].row()
        print(selection)
        
        self.mainWidget.setText(str(selection))
    

    def buttonPressed(self):
        if self.buttonState:
            self.sidebar.contractAnimation.start()
        else:
            self.sidebar.expandAnimation.start()
        
        self.buttonState = not self.buttonState
    

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec()
```

This works well with my theme that I use (WhiteSur on KDE), but I couldn't just use self.iconSize().width() for the minimum width, because it would cut off the icon, I had to use self.iconSize().width() + 16, but this means that when I use another theme, like Breeze, it's too wide, I have to use a number like 10. And also with the Breeze theme, the sidebar itself can be selected and have a blue border around it, which I don't want. Is there a way to get the proper icon size that respects the padding and all that, and also a way to make the sidebar itself not selectable? Or is there a better way to make a native-looking sidebar that I can animate expanding and collapsing?

Comment: Why don't you just use an arbitrary value as a *minimum*? `iconWidth = max(16, self.iconSize().width())`

Comment: No, it's self.iconSize().width + 16, and with Breeze it's self.iconSize().width() + 10, and I assume on other themes it will be something else, right now I have no way of knowing what those values are. Also, self.iconSize().width() always returns the same number, because I set the icon size myself.

Comment: If you want to base your widget to the current style, you have to comply to the current Qt style. Start by studying how [QStyle](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html) works; for instance, the default icon size (if not set) is based on `view.style().pixelMetric(QStyle.PM_SmallIconSize, QStyleOption(), view)`.

Comment: Note: please try to choose titles and contents of your questions carefully: your issue is not about getting the "padding" or a "native sidebar", but getting the correct icon size. While those things may be related, you must try to focus on the actual issue, and keep the rest as *context*, so that we may better focus on helping you instead of being distracted by finding where the actual problem is. This is not only a good practice to consider for SO (or any other related service), but even for basic debugging: focus on the issue, separate it from the context, while considering their relations.

Comment: I don't get what you're saying. I set the icon size myself. And even if I don't set the icon size, `view.style().pixelMetric(QStyle.PM_SmallIconSize, QStyleOption(), view)` gives me 16, and if I set the minimum width to 16, it still cuts off the icon. So there is obviously some padding around the icon to make the size I need larger than 16

Comment: Ok, I was under the impression that you wanted to get the default icon size. Since you want to override that, doing `iconWidth = self.iconSize().width()` is quite pointless: you already know that value. And that's not just a *padding*, it's a *spacing*, because the "padding" you want to show on the right is actually the space between the icon and the text, and there is absolutely no guarantee that it would be respected: you could have a large padding around items, but a small spacing between the icon and the text, and that would look ugly.

Comment: I believe that the only *safe* solution (if you want to ensure that it would look fine on any style and system) would be to use a custom delegate: you can then ensure that the size is always consistent no matter what the style would do, and then you can do the item painting on your own, based on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to fix it by creating a custom QStyledItemDelegate. I created a regular delegate without the icons or text, and then painted the icon and text on top of it. [Code](https://topaz.github.io/paste/#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)

Comment: Please improve your post by providing a [mre], as using external resources as only reference for the implementation is discouraged.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).